# SSL Certificates for multiple domains heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I have 2 domain names (English Version & German version) for my heroku hosted app

www.example.com     &   www.beispiel.com

I purchased an SSL certificate for www.example.com...can I now 'point' www.beispiel.com to this domain or do i need to purchase a seperate SSL certificate?

Comment: This would be better for [webmaster SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) and I believe it has already been asked over there. Have you tried looking there?

Comment: No, but I will, Thanks